# Add count text field in android searchview

Tags: android, textview, searchview

I have a searchview in my mainmenu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    android:title="@string/view_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
```

I want to show a textview on the right side of the searchview with the count of the search results. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can include a textview in the toolbar and show the count, refer this [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar) for better understanding.

I have a sample code here:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
 />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

or you can do the same in action bar, refer this [link](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android) for action bar with customView

Comment: The toolbar gets hidden when the searchview expands.

Comment: then try to include a textView in action bar or customize the searchView by using an AutocompleteTextView and set a custom width and then try including the textView for count, refer this [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/pro-tip-customize-the-android-search-view-widget/) for custom searchView

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you're getting your results from, online or local. In any case, when you get the results, either call a "count" query or fill a List (ArrayList) or anything of the sort.
At the end, all you need to do is

```
textview.setText(String.valueOf(results.size()));
// or
textview.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

Remember to call this method from the main thread.

Comment: I'm more interested in how to get a textview inside the searchview, to the right of the edittext view

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the count text to a drawable and using the searchview's edittext's right compound drawable to display this count in the searchview's query listener.